# How to script a string from a txt file to be inserted into a given variable in turn?

Tags: applescript, automation, macos

I have a text file with names. Each name is on a new line.

```
Bob
Robert
John 
Leslie
Anna
```

How can I read this text file with AppleScript so that I can use the name in each line to send an iMessage to somebody by replacing `LINE-FROM-FILE` with one name from the file?

```
tell application "Messages"
      set theBuddy to buddy "LINE-FROM-FILE" of service "iCloud"
      send "Hi there" to theBuddy
end tell
```

Comment: Where in your code so you access the text file?

Comment: So you basically need some code to read a text file, and then for each line in the file send the same message to the contact matching the name?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReadandWriteFiles.html, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064849/read-textfile-into-list-in-applescript, https://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/applescript-read-file-into-list-array-examples, https://iworkautomation.com/numbers/table-read-file.html